# Finite index subgroup of Chevalley groups over $\Bbb C$

Tags: algebraic-topology, lie-groups, algebraic-groups

I'm trying to show that if $G$ is a Chevalley group, then every finite indexed subgroup of $G(\Bbb Z)$ is Zariski dense in $G(\Bbb C)$. ($G(\Bbb Z)$ is the Chevalley group over $\Bbb Z$ and similarly for $G(\Bbb C)$)

But I'm struggling to understand some basic stuff,
It seems to me that there can't be finite index subgroup in $G(\Bbb C)$ how can I show that?

Comment: I don't understand. Take $G=\mathbb{G}_m$. Then you're claiming that $\{\pm 1\}$ is Zariski dense in $\mathbb{C}^\times$, aren't you?

Comment: I don't think $\mathbb G_m$ is a Chevalley group but in this case, I believe $\mathbb G_m(\mathbb Z)=\mathbb Z$ witch is Zariski-dense

Comment: $\mathbb{G}_m(\mathbb{Z})=\{\pm 1\}$.

Comment: oops yeah, you are right, but like I said $\mathbb G_m$ is not a Chevalley group. Chevalley groups are without nontrivial rational characters so Borel-Harish-Chandra implies $G(\mathbb Z)$ is a lattice in $G(\mathbb R)$